# SQLite reads with multiprocessing, not starting the imap

Tags: python, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

I've tried everything I could think of, but I can not figure out why the following multiprocessing code will not start the loop:

```
import sqlite3, itertools

# Dummy table
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE numbers (num integer)')
conn.executemany("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (?)",
                 ((x,) for x in range(5)))
conn.commit()

cmd_search = "SELECT * FROM numbers"
cursor = conn.execute(cmd_search)

def nothing(x): return x

import multiprocessing
P = multiprocessing.Pool()
#ITR  = P.imap(nothing,cursor)           # parallel version
ITR  = itertools.imap(nothing, cursor)   # serial   version

for x in ITR: print x
```

When I run it with the "serial" version (using `itertools.imap`) I get the expected output of `(0,) (1,) (2,) (3,) (4,)`. Using the `multiprocessing.imap` version, I get nothing and the loop exits silently. I clearly has to do with the sqlite cursor, switching to `cursor=range(5)` works.

Why won't multiprocessing work here?

Comment: When I run this on my Ubuntu machine, I get a very explicit error: `ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140082824808256 and this is thread id 140082770409216`.

Comment: @dano Strange, on my machine it silently exits. I'm using python `2.7.9` on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: I've got 2.7.6 on 14.04. I was able to get passed that error by using `conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", check_same_thread=False)`. With that change, the program works fine.

Comment: @dano Thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Something is strange here, if I got that message I think I could have solved it on my own. Perhaps it is something with the new OS? Either way I'll leave this question up for others to find on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `sqlite3` won't let you access any of its object outside of hte thread that actually created it. `multiprocessing.Pool` uses a background thread to queue up objects, which violates this rule. You can disable that check, though by passing `check_same_thread=False` to `sqlite3.connect`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", check_same_thread=False)
```

Once I made that change, your code ran fine. Without that change, I was seeing this error:

```
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140082824808256 and this is thread id 140082770409216
```

I'm not sure why you weren't seeing any error message; the only way I didn't get one is if I removed the `for x in ITR: print x` line, since without it you don't actually try to retrieve results from the `Pool`, which will suppress any errors that occurred inside it.